# Creating a Webhook for NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, webhooks

My client is using NetSuite and wants to integrate with Commonsku - Commonsku says they can do this via a Webhook. How do I create a webhook in NetSuite? Is this even possible?  Thank you.

Meg

Answer (score 1):

Perform an HTTP call to Commonsku via User Event, whenever there's a relevant change to one of your NetSuite records. Example: If the item weight changes, then use the N/https to post the updated values to the Commonsku API endpoint.